# Flatten multilevel column in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like

```
In [1]: df
Out[1]:
   a  b  c
   d  e  f
   g  h  i
0  1  2  3
1  4  5  6
2  7  8  9
```

where first 3 rows are columns

```
In [2]: df.columns.values
Out[2]: array([('a', 'd', 'g'), ('b', 'e', 'h'), ('c', 'f', 'i')], dtype=object)
```

I want to convert this dataframe to

```
   a  b  c
0  d  e  f
1  g  h  i
2  1  2  3
3  4  5  6
4  7  8  9
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `reset_index`

```
df=df.T.reset_index(level=[1,2]).T
```